# Как очистить блок?

Tags: html, css

Есть лендинг: http://www.sosedi-medvedi.com/
Как убрать блок

```
>> РАБОТАЕМ ПО ВСЕЙ РОССИИ!
```

Необходимо убрать его полностью. Пытался очень много раз, не выходило, так как оставался лишь пустой блок. Другие блоки не смещаются вверх. Наглядная картинка:   http://savepic.org/6217868.png

*Помогите, пожалуйста.*

Comment: @yodet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

там какая-то ущербная верстка, нужно убить #u11449 и поднимать нижележащие блоки, иначе никак, думаю.

> Человеку, который на самом деле мне поможет закину 100 WMR.

Вы же понимаете, что тут у каждого второго достаточная з/п, чтобы эти деньги заработать, просто *не* тратя время на просмотр этого вопроса?